# Undefined object title after push function

Tags: node.js, express

I am learning to code using express js but I encountered a problem today, le me show you some code:

```
      //main js file

      const express=require('express');

      const app=express();

      const path=require('path');

      const dirRoot =require('./util/path')

      const bodyParser=require('body-parser');

      const adminData = require('./routes/admin.js');
      const shopRoute= require('./routes/shop.js');




        app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname , 'public')));

        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));

        app.use('/admin',adminData.routes);

       app.use(shopRoute);

       app.listen(2000);





//----------------
//admin.js
const products=[];

router.get('/add-product',(req,res,next)=>{
res.sendFile(path.join(dirRoot, 'views', 'home.html'));

 //<form action="/admin/add-product" method="post" >
 //   <input name ="title" type="text">
 //   <button>Send</button>
 // </form>                           <-- this form is contained in home.html

});

router.post('/add-product',(req,res,next)=>{
products.push({title:req.body.title});
res.redirect('/');
});

 exports.routes=router;

 exports.products=products;

 //-----------------------
 //shop.js

 const adminData=require('./admin.js');


  router.get('/',(req,res,next)=>{
  console.log(adminData.products);
  res.sendFile(path.join(dirRoot,'views','success.html'))
  });

  module.exports=router;
```

Everything seems to work properly but in the console I am not being able to display the user text input, I get just [ { title: undefined } ].

I also tried removing the .title specification from req.body, and it looks like this: 
[ { title: [Object: null prototype] { inserimento: 'bedduxsdsdsds' } } ]

in eiher ways there is something wrong that I am doing, could anyone spot what is being incorrect?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am using the body-parses in my main file yes.

Comment: You're not posting title, but: `inserimento`, do: `console.log(req.body)`

Comment: Thanks man! I did not know that the name you give to the inputs is related to what I was doing! thank you very much!